# The checkbox in the DataGridTemplateColumn is malfunctional

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

I add a DataGridTemplateColumn with a checkbox to my Datagrid in Silverlight. The Checkbox is successfully added to the datagrid as a column. However,if I check more that one chcekbox, some other checkboxes in this column will be affected automatically (i.e.,changed from checked to unchecked, or vise versa.). I didn't add any event handler for this checkbox, so how could this happen? It seems to me, if I scroll the datagrid to view more records, the datagrid is refreshed/updated automatically, and the checkboxes are messed up at that point. My code is listed below:

```
            DataGridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn() { Header = "header",Width=new DataGridLength(50) };               
            StringBuilder CellTemp = new StringBuilder();
            CellTemp.Append("<DataTemplate ");
            CellTemp.Append("xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/");
            CellTemp.Append("2006/xaml/presentation' ");
            CellTemp.Append("xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' >");
            CellTemp.Append("<CheckBox  x:Name='" + "checkBoxHeader" + "' Margin='4'  IsChecked='False'/>");
            CellTemp.Append("</DataTemplate>");
            templateColumn.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(CellTemp.ToString());
            ftrDataGrid.Columns.Add(templateColumn);
```

How should I resolve this problem, should I add an event handler to this datagrid, but how?

Many thanks for your input,

Wei

Comment: That's because the DataGrid is expecting a commit which it does not get by just clicking. If you bind the data, change the Update property of the binding to PropertyChanged. Probably Silverlight 5, but maybe also in 4

Comment: Thanks, Silvermind. I am not good at binding. How should I binding to the checkbox? The initial checkbox is not correlated with any attribute from the dataSource attached to the datagrid, I just want  all of them unchecked at first. Should I use a Dictionary to record/binding which are been checked?

Comment: Perhaps you could use the example given by @TriggerPin but you would have to follow my previous comment in that. If your data is not correlated to your data source than you might want to consider making a wrapper class for it, a so called ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up Binding in the Template is as easy as this:

```
DataGridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn() { Header 
...

CellTemp.Append("<CheckBox  x:Name='" + "checkBoxHeader" + "' Margin='4'  IsChecked="{Binding MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay}"/>");
...            
ftrDataGrid.Columns.Add(templateColumn);
```

Where MyProperty is a Boolean.